# Issue scaling an object with array modifier around empty

Tags: modifiers, scale

I have a "pizza slice" with angle of 45 degrees and array modifier to make full circle of it

[image]

I need to scale the whole circle down but when i'm trying to do it, something wierd happens.

[image]

How to scale an entire object if an Empty is in the center of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've scaled down the object, apply the scale with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*, otherwise the offset object will act like a multiplier.